# If $f(\theta)=\min\left(|2x-7|+|x-4|+|x-2-\sin(\theta)|\right)$, where $x, \theta \in R$, then maximum value of $f(\theta)$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> > If $f(\theta)=\min\left(|2x-7|+|x-4|+|x-2-\sin(\theta)|\right)$, where $x, \theta \in R$, then maximum value of $f(\theta)$ is

**My Approach:**

Since $2+\sin(\theta)<\dfrac{7}{2}<4$.

**Case 1:**
$x\geq4$

$f(\theta)=4x-13-\sin(\theta)$

$f(\theta)\geq2$ because $x\geq4\implies f(\theta)\geq 3-\sin(\theta)\implies f(\theta)\geq 2$

**Case 2:**

$\dfrac{7}{2}\leq x<4$

$f(\theta)=2x-5-\sin(\theta)$

In this case

$f(\theta)\geq 2-\sin(\theta)\implies f(\theta)\geq1$

**Case 3:**

$2+\sin(\theta)<x<\dfrac{7}{2}$

$f(\theta)=-2x+9-\sin(\theta)$

In this case $f(\theta)>2-\sin(\theta) \implies f(\theta)>1$

**Case 4:**

$x\leq2+\sin (\theta)$

$f(\theta)=-4x+13+\sin(\theta)$

In this case $f(\theta)\geq 5-3\sin(\theta)\implies f(\theta)\geq2$

So from **Case 1, Case 2, Case 3, Case 4**

$f(\theta)=2-\sin (\theta)$

Hence $\max(f(\theta))=3$.

Is my approach correct? Also is there any short method to solve this problem?

Comment: $f$ is, as defined, only a function of $\theta$, so the focus should be on the last term [where $\theta$ shows up].

Comment: @Math-fun But $\theta$ shows up in every case. I think I did not understood what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short method uses the fact that a minimizer of the sum of absolute distances from the points of a data set $x_i \in \mathbb R,\: i=1,\ldots , n$ is a **median** $x_M$ of the data set:
$$ \min \sum_{i=1}^n|x-x_i| = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_M-x_i|$$

For your function write
$$f(\theta) = \min(|x- 3.5| + |x-3.5| + |x-4| + |x-(2+\sin \theta)|)$$
So, a minimizer is
$$x_M = 3.5 \quad \text{This is the median of } 2+\sin \theta,\; 3.5,\;3.5,\;4$$
Now, plug in $x_M = 3.5$ and maximize
$$\max f(\theta) = \max_{\theta \in [0,2\pi]}(0.5 + |1.5-\sin \theta |) = 0.5+2.5 = \boxed{3}$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/enddwvefjv) you can check it graphically. Maximum is attained at $\theta = \frac 32 \pi $.